# Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://localhost/js/test.js”

Tags: javascript, firefox, message, content-script

Background script:

```
let show_floater = true;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (event) {
    console.log('clicked');
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'js/content.js', /* my content script */   }, () => {
            connect(show_floater) //this is where I call my function to establish a connection     
        });
    });
});

function connect(sf) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
        console.log(show_floater, sf);
        const port = chrome.tabs.connect(tabs[0].id);

        console.log('doing stuff);

        port.postMessage(sf);
    });
}
```

Content script:

```
let var injected = false;

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener((port) => {
    port.onMessage.addListener((show_floater) => {
        if (!show_floater) {
            injected = 0;
            document.querySelector(".beebole_css").remove();
            document.querySelector(".beebole_js").remove();
            document.querySelector(".beebole_container").remove();
            //document.querySelector(".beebole_button").remove();
        }
        else if (!injected) {
            injected = true;

            let link = document.createElement("link");
            link.className = 'beebole_css';
            link.href = "https://localhost/css/test.css";
            link.type = "text/css";
            link.rel = "stylesheet";
            document.querySelector("head").appendChild(link);

            let s = document.createElement("script");
            s.className = 'beebole_js';
            s.src = "https://localhost/js/test.js";
            s.type = 'text/javascript';
            // document.body.appendChild(s);
            document.querySelector('body').appendChild(s);
        }
    });
});
```

The above code runs on Chrome but on Firefox I get this error

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://localhost/js/test.js”.
```

this is my manifest

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Counterstring",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "simple counterstring generation",
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": [
            "js/content.js"
        ]
    }
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://localhost/js/test.js; object-src 'self'",
    "background": {
        "persistent": true,
        "scripts": [
            "js/background.js"
        ]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "deafult_icon": "icons/icon16x16.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus",
        "activeTab",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/icon16x16.png",
        "48": "icons/icon48x48.png",
        "128": "icons/icon128x128.png"
    }
}
```

**Side quest:**

in the above manifest I put the content_scripts because I got a permission error if i did not but from my understanding from [here](https://www.bennettnotes.com/post/fix-receiving-end-does-not-exist/) I should be able to avoid that by using postMessage(). Is my understanding flawed?

Comment: @expressjs123 how would I handle it then? Because on Chrome it works no problem but on Firefox no.

Answer (score 0):

found solution, the problem was that I had no SSL certificate for authorising my localhost on Firefox.